# IPN validation doesn't fail when it should fail

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am trying to set up PayPal to process payments. Everything is working OK except the fact that payments are not being cancelled when my IPN doesn't send a validation message to PayPal. As far as I understand if the IPN didn't validate the payment the transaction supposed to be cancelled.
The code looks like that:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Receive()
{
    //Store the IPN received from PayPal
    LogRequest(Request);

    Task.Run(() => VerifyTask(Request));

    //Reply back a 200 code
    return new EmptyResult();
}

private void VerifyTask(HttpRequest ipnRequest)
{
    try
    {
        VerifyIpnParamsWithException(ipnRequest);
        var verificationRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr");

        //Set values for the verification request
        verificationRequest.Method = "POST";
        verificationRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        var param = ReadRequestBody(ipnRequest.Body);
        var strRequest = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(param);

        //Add cmd=_notify-validate to the payload
        strRequest = "cmd=_notify-validate&" + strRequest;
        verificationRequest.ContentLength = strRequest.Length;

        //Attach payload to the verification request
        using (var streamOut = new StreamWriter(verificationRequest.GetRequestStream(), Encoding.ASCII))
        {
            streamOut.Write(strRequest);
            streamOut.Close();
        }
        var verificationResponse = string.Empty;

        //Send the request to PayPal and get the response
        using (var streamIn = new StreamReader(verificationRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
        {
            verificationResponse = streamIn.ReadToEnd();
            streamIn.Close();
        }
        ProcessVerificationResponse(verificationResponse);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        DAL.LogError(exception, ipnRequest);
    }
}
```

When I tested it, according to my log an exception was thrown before a verification message was sent to PayPal. It didn't change the fact that the money was transferred to the PayPal account and the transaction is completed. Did I misunderstand? Is there anything else I'm supposed to do in order to cancel the transaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IPN functionality is to notify the merchant about the payment movements which includes ;

- Payments received, including Express Checkout, and Adaptive Payments.
- Credit card authorizations.
- eCheck payments and related pending, completed, or denied status events.
- Recurring payments and subscription actions.
- Chargebacks, disputes, reversals, and refunds

IPN does not cancelled a payments if you are not validating the text sent over to your Listener.

Further articles from PayPal : https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/

Comment: Interesting. In that case, is there any other way to validate the payment was not altered by the client except using saved buttons, which have very limited abilities? Is PayPal API (which is extremely annoying) the only way to go?

Comment: IPN basically are two way of communication, which PayPal sends you message and your listener will post-back the message with unaltered text. This will ensure the transaction was originally from PayPal.